# Cannot find existing route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3

I have this route

```
get 'versions' => 'main#versions', formats: [:xml]
```

In my `MainController`, I have an action `versions` thus:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def versions
    render formats: [:xml]
  end
end
```

and under `app/views/main` I have `versions.xml.erb`.

I have written an RSpec controller test:

require 'rails_helper'

```
RSpec.describe MainController, type: :controller do
  ...

  describe '#versions' do
    it 'renders versions template' do
      get :versions, formats: [:xml]

      expect(response).to render_template(:versions)
    end
  end
end
```

However, I continue to get this error:

```
Failure/Error: get :versions, formats: [:xml]

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"versions", :controller=>"main", :formats=>["xml"]}
```

However, when I run `rake routes`, I get:

```
versions GET  /versions(.:format)   main#versions {:formats=>[:xml]}
```

I still don't understand why I'm getting this error when the route exists with the right parameters.

Ruby 2.1.5
Rails 4.1.6
RSpec 3.8.x

NOTE: I'm constrained to not rewrite any code and can only suggest changes.

Answer (score 0):

Rails' routing uses a `format` key, not `formats`. It's automatically supported for all endpoints by default, and will pass on whatever format is required to your controller actions.

I'd suggest the following modifications:

```
# routes.rb
get 'versions', to: 'main#versions'

# main_controller.rb
def versions
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml
  end
end

# main_controller_spec.rb
it 'renders the version template' do
   get :versions, format: :xml
   ...
end
```

Comment: I agree @scott-mathewman, that's what I'd do. However, I'm constrained here and cannot introduce changes but make recommendation. However, I need to be sure the approach is wrong before making my recommendation. The thing is this works in production and development and fails in test.